# SQL,how to select attributes from different tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

i want so select user_name,vehicle_name and maintain_cost from 3 different tables where user_id,vehicle_id and maintain_cost_id is equal to three,so which query i used,i try this

```
(select user_name,vehicle_name,maintain_cost
from user,vehicle,maintain_cost
where user_id='3')
```

but do not know how to put vehicle_id='3' and maintain_cost_id='3'

Comment: What's the schema of user, vehicale, maintain_cost?

Answer (score 0):

Use a left join, an example can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, just adapt it with the real ids:

```
SELECT user_name,vehicle_name,maintain_cost
FROM USER u 
LEFT JOIN vehicle v ON v.user_id=u.user_id 
LEFT JOIN maintain_cost m ON m.vehicle_id=v.vehicle_id
WHERE u.user_id=3 AND v.vehicle_id=3 AND maintain_cost_id=3
```